# Salesforce app - how to prevent refresh on connection restored?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, mobile, app

So I have an app page with screen flow and LWC components. I have observed that when the internet connection is lost the app is showing gray toast informing about it. When the connection is restored the app refreshes all the components on page automatically which I would like to avoid

Is there any way to prevent or disable (like it can be done with disabling pull to refresh) auto reloading components on internet connection restored?